# Click button, resize view

Tags: macos, webview, width

Im new to programming and obviously not that good. But I'm trying to search my way to success! But unfortunately I'm bad at it too.

Im doing an Mac OS X app with a webview and a few buttons. When I'm clicking one button I want the webview to change size.

One thing I could to is to add lots of web views and show and hide them, but I think it most be easier to change the webview on a button click.

```
- (IBAction)changeButton:(id)sender {

   self.webview.HowToChangeTheSize = unKnown;

   NSLog(@"Button works");

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change a webview size could be used frame property.

```
- (IBAction)changeButton:(id)sender {

  self.webview.frame = CGRectMake(self.webview.frame.origin.x, self.webview.frame.origin.y, 200, 200);

   NSLog(@"Button works");
}
```

This will change your webview's height and width to 200.

Comment: That worked like a charm! If I want to position it to the top left or center it, how can I make this changes? I mean after hitting the button.

Comment: Modify values for first two parameters passed to CGRectMake function. So if you want to position it to the top left, you need to set 0 to webview's frame origin coordinates:self.webview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200);